# Gitlab pipeline job takes too long

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Normally in my project pipeline job for tests takes about 20min (gitlab runners) to finish on gitlab, and (2min locally on macOS). Something about 2 months ago there where a problem with running this job with no reason (no change in the code at all), the job took over 59min and it was automatically canceled by gitlab.

Then I spend a time to run it on locally gitlabrunner using docker, and It worked fine. After few days of investigation when I ran the same pipeline it just finish with success and it was like that since last week. Now again I cannot run pipeline because job is just hanging for an hour and then it is canceled.

Comment: That can have multiple reasons. Power of the gitlab runner - the runner is shared and pipe needs to wait until your job starts - no env configured on gitlab so external dependencies like the DB/... are not starting and app waits for it - locally using test parallelization and on pipe not - ...

In order to identify your issue, there should be more info provided.

Comment: We'll need some more details about what exactly your job is doing (or at least _should_ be doing) when this problem happens. Ideally you should have some kind of logging output that should let you know where your job is getting stuck. Are you running any memory or CPU intensive programs? Are you communicating with external systems? What does your code under test actually do?